# How to use grunt-bower-install to update multiple html files

Tags: gruntjs, bower-install

I'm using the grunt file generated by yeoman angular-generator. There are multiple files need bower-install to update, the bower-install config is now like

```
// Automatically inject Bower components into the app
'bower-install': {
  app: {
    html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
    ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/'
  }
},
```

I tried to use

```
    html: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html','<%= yeoman.app %>/manager.html']
```

And when running `grunt bower-install`, I got the following error

```
Running "bower-install:app" (bower-install) task
Warning: path must be a string Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

The bower-install plugin version is

```
"grunt-bower-install": "~0.7.0",
```

And my question is does this version support update multiple html files? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define multiple targets to update multiple html files like this:

```
'bower-install': {
  app: {
    html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
    ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/'
  },
  app2: {
    html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/manager.html',
    ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the latest version uses a much more flexible way of targeting files for injection...

https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-bower-install

```
target: {
    ...
    src: [
      'app/views/**/*.html',
    ...
```